# Studiologic Fatar SL 760 2 midi out

Tags: midi

I have a Studiologic fatar SL 760 with 2 midi out ports not the usual 1 in, 1 out midi ports. I have tried the usual 1 in, 1 out to usb cable without success. Can you suggest how I can get the 2 out midi ports to work for my Mac book? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The two ports output the same signal. Just connect one output to the computer's input, and ignore the other one.